# CMUSphinx with custom features

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to train a new accoustic model for speechrecognition, with custom features. Is it possible to feed the feature matrix instead of wav file into CMUSphinx for training? I have tried searching on google and the tutorial page and can't find any information about it. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to feed the feature matrix instead of wav file into CMUSphinx for training?

It is better to train with more modern toolkit like Kaldi.

> I have tried searching on google and the tutorial page and can't find any information about it. Am i missing something?

You just prepare mfc files yourself and skip first feature_extraction step. You have to write code for that like described here:

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/mfcformat/

In kaldi you just prepare ark files yourself:

https://pypi.org/project/kaldiio/

Comment: Actually, kaldi was my first choice, mostly because the python wrapper. But I got stuck when trying to create a transition model, because I can't seem to find the format for the tree structure to build the ContextDependency object. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.